# Panda Series Exercise SyntaxError

Tags: pandas

-[Panda Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk4QV.png)

*I wrote the code below but still it doesn't appear as on top, and showed SyntaxError: invalid syntax* Where did I go wrong, I followed the sample XD

import panda as pd
pd.Series([4 cups,1 cup,2 large,1 can], index=['Flour', 'Milk', 'Eggs', 'Spam'], name='Dinner')

Comment: Use `pd.DataFrame(['4 cups','1 cup','2 large','1 can'], index=['Flour', 'Milk', 'Eggs', 'Spam'], columns=['Dinner'])`

Comment: change `[4 cups,1 cup,2 large,1 can]` to `['4 cups','1 cup','2 large','1 can']`. You need to pass as string, python will try to match these as identifiers if the quotes are not present.